# When printing out lines from a file, in the python executor it has a line gap between each line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have got ASCII art in a file which I want to print out, however, when I go to print it out it leaves one line per line in the file, making the ASCII art not look like art.

I've got it working and it's fully functional, but I was wondering how I would get rid of the one line problem.

```
if user_input == "4":
    print('''You have selected [4] Display ASCII art.
        You will enter a file name, and the ASCII art will be printed..''')
    file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
    new_file_name = file_name + '.txt'
    with open(new_file_name) as file_handle:
        for line in file_handle:
            print(line)
            time.sleep(0.3)
    printProgramRestart()
```

I want the new output to look like art, all clustered into one but it doesn't.

Comment: Each line in the file ends with a newline character, and `print` adds one too. Maybe set `end=""` to suppress `print`'s, or use `.strip()` to remove the line's.

Comment: I'm new to python, I'm not sure about how I would do that.

Comment: Then **read the docs**: [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

Answer (score 0):

print function has end parameter (as explained in the comments)

so when printing a line use:

```
print(line, end='')
```

Comment: One problem, the function which I used then goes onto the same line.

Comment: Just add print() at the end of the function

Answer (score 0):

Every time you print it will be on a new line, and when you read the .txt file it already includes newline signs (\n). You can either print everything at the same time instead, or add an .strip('\n') which removes the newlines:

```py
        for line in file_handle:
            print(line.strip('\n'))
            time.sleep(0.3)
```